# Installing hundreds of packages listed in a text file using apt in ansible

Tags: automation, ansible, apt

I used to just
`sudo apt install -y "$(cat pkg_apt)"` and I want to do something similar in Ansible

I don't understand what are roles and why I need to use them.

I don't want to indent and fit into yaml file every package since there are hundreds of them that I have stored in a file from `apt-mark showmanual`
I am running this on my local machine.

Where should I put the packages? In inventory file? in Var directory? in roles?

If I just have to use commands and load them into variable and do loop over them, then what is the point of ansible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want to indent and fit into yaml file every package since there are hundreds of them that I have stored in a file from `apt-mark showmanual`. I am running this on my local machine.

I'll let you read on [roles](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html) but we really don't need one at this point for the below example.

Demo project structure

```
$ tree
.
├── pkg_apt
└── playbook.yml

0 directories, 2 files
```

This can be stored in your favorite versionning system and updated whenever you make changes to your system.

Stripped content of `pkg_apt` as gotten on my local machine using the same command as yours (i.e. `apt-mark showmanual > pkg_apt`)

```
locate
login
lsb-release
make
memtest86+
mokutil
mousetweaks
```

From there, what we have to do is extremely simple:

1. load the above file into a usable list
2. feed that list to the `apt` module at once into the `name` option so that all packages are installed during the same apt transaction. We don't want to `loop:`. See the [notes on `apt` module documentations](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_module.html#notes)

   > When used with a `loop:` each package will be processed individually, it is much more efficient to pass the list directly to the `name` option.

The resulting `playbook.yml` looks like this:

```yaml
---
- name: Restore packages on system from a saved package list
  hosts: localhost
  become: true
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    package_file: pkg_apt
    package_list: "{{ lookup('file', package_file) | split('\n') }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Install all packages in {{ package_file }} through apt
      ansible.builtin.apt:
        name: "{{ package_list }}"
        state: present
```

which gives on my local machine (note: `apt` is reporting "ok" as expected since the packages are already installed on my system)

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml 

PLAY [Restore packages on system from a saved package list] **********

TASK [Install all packages in pkg_apt through apt] ***********
ok: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

Since you mentioned using a single command line before as a bit of a frustration, note that all the above can be summarized into a single [ansible ad-hoc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/command_guide/intro_adhoc.html) one-liner running from the directory where you stored the file:

```bash
ansible localhost -b -m apt \
-e "package_list={{ lookup('file', 'pkg_apt') | split('\n') }}" \
-a "name={{ package_list }} state=present"
```

Comment: thank you sir really helpful input.
i will look into roles too but what I have here is perfect. should i put the pkg_apt file in a certain directory to make it more organised or do i just leave it in the root of the ansible folder

Comment: This is really up to you. For something as simple that would be perfectly ok. The `files` subfolder is an other good place (read https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/tips_tricks/sample_setup.html). But that really depends on the final complexity of your overall project. I gave an example for a single task running on localhost as described in the question. And for what it's worth: I like the tone of your above comment much better than the one which got deleted earlier. Please keep it this way for your next interactions on this site. Regards.